# Copy and paste to new column in another sheet Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have data on sheet 1 with time in column A and current column B. The data for multiple runs is all in one column so I want to separate each run into a new column.

The measurements are variable length so I want excel to find the 0 values in column A and copy the corresponding values in column b until a new 0 value is found in column a to a new column in sheet 2.

So far, excel will successfully find the data in column b and will copy it over to sheet2 but it fills the entire column with that data by repeatedly copy-pasting until all the columns I have copied data into filled except the first and last column. How can I fix this? Here is what I have so far:

```
    Sub CopyValuestoSheet2()
Dim strsearch As String
Dim lastline As Integer
Dim tocopy As Integer
Dim StartValue As Integer
Dim FinishValue As Integer
Dim Col2 As Integer
Dim TempValue As Integer
Dim EndValue As Integer

strsearch = CStr(InputBox("enter time to search for (usually 0)"))
lastline = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Col2 = 1
TempValue = 1

For i = 2 To lastline
    'This part selects the data in column B based off of finding the value in column A
    For Each c In Range("A" & i & ":A" & i)
        If InStr(c.Text, strsearch) Then
            tocopy = 1
            StartValue = TempValue
            FinishValue = i
            TempValue = FinishValue
            FinishValue = FinishValue - 1
        End If
    Next c
'Here is where I actually copy the data over
 If tocopy = 1 Then
        'I want to copy the range row StartValue to row FinishValue in column B
        Range("B" & StartValue & ":B" & FinishValue).Copy
    'I want to paste it to a new column each time
        Paste Destination:=Sheets(2).Columns(Col2)
        Col2 = Col2 + 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
tocopy = 0
Next i
    'Printing the last data point since there is no 0 after the final entry.
    'This part works fine even though it is just a copy-paste of the If statement
        FinishValue = FinishValue + 1
        'This will fail if the last datapoint has more thatn 500 enteries
        EndValue = FinishValue + 500
        Range("B" & FinishValue & ":B" & EndValue).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Paste Destination:=Sheets(2).Columns(Col2)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing your check to see if column A values *contain* `strSearch` rather than if the *are exactly* `strSearch`.  Assuming `strSearch = 0`, is it possible it's picking up non-0's because the A value contains a 0?  Would need to see some sample data.

Comment: How would I specify only picking up exactly 0's and not just numbers containing 0's? I just tested it and that is an issue also.

Answer (score 0):

this should be better :

```
Sub CopyValuestoSheet2()
    Dim strsearch As String
    Dim lastline As Integer
    Dim tocopy As Integer
    Dim StartValue As Integer
    Dim FinishValue As Integer
    Dim Col2 As Integer
    Dim TempValue As Integer
    Dim EndValue As Integer

strsearch = CStr(InputBox("enter time to search for (usually 0)"))
lastline = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Col2 = 1
TempValue = 1

For I = 2 To lastline
    'This part selects the data in column B based off of finding the value in column A
    For Each c In Range("A" & I & ":A" & I)
        If InStr(c.Text, strsearch) Then
            tocopy = 1
            StartValue = TempValue
            FinishValue = I
            TempValue = FinishValue
            FinishValue = FinishValue - 1
        End If
    Next c
'Here is where I actually copy the data over
 If tocopy = 1 Then
        'I want to copy the range row StartValue to row FinishValue in column B
        Range("B" & StartValue & ":B" & FinishValue).Copy
    'I want to paste it to a new column each time
        Paste Destination:=Sheets(2).Range(ColLet(Col2) & "$1:$" & ColLet(Col2) & (FinishValue - StartValue + 1))
        Col2 = Col2 + 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
tocopy = 0
Next I
    'Printing the last data point since there is no 0 after the final entry.
    'This part works fine even though it is just a copy-paste of the If statement
        FinishValue = FinishValue + 1
        'This will fail if the last datapoint has more thatn 500 enteries
        EndValue = Range("B" & FinishValue).End(xlDown).Row
        Range(Range("B" & FinishValue), Range("B" & EndValue)).Copy

        Paste Destination:=Sheets(2).Range(ColLet(Col2) & "$1:$" & ColLet(Col2) & (EndValue - FinishValue + 1))


End Sub
```

And for your information, .select is a very greedy (in ressources) and generaly useless command, so try to avoid it! ;)

```
Public Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String
With ActiveSheet.Columns(x)
    ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: How does the ColLet function work? When I tried this solution, I get a compile error that says the Sub or Function not defined and the first instance of ColLet is highlighted. I tried defining it as a string, integer, long, and as a range but that didn't seem to help any.